# Component child with two parents,

Tags: reactjs

im newbie on Ractsjs, and now i made on course on Plural sight, the situation its the fallowing, i have one component(child) who is the son and in one hand i have a one component2(father) thats send the 'props' for the component3(son) use them; and for other hand, this component3(son) wants send a callback function to the other component1(father),

in resthat´s my schema:
                             Component1           Component3
                                 |with callbaclk   |    with props
                                 |                 |
                                 └   Component3    ┘

::The seem child receive 'props' from on component(father1) and this seem child component need send a callback function to the other component(father2).........how i can do it??

thks in advance

pd) i attached my code
https://github.com/jmonteros81/Building_-Applications_React

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PytY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are used to send data from child to parent. Callbacks are just simple functions. So you have to write a callback in your parent component and Call that callback from your Child component from where you want to send data to parent.
In Parent component define a function.

```
getAndPassValue(value) {
   this.setState({ count: value });
}
```

in render pass this function to your child

```
<ThirdComponent getAndPassValue={this.getAndPassValue} />
```

In Child component from where you want to pass data to parent call this function.

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.passvalue(5)} />
```

Now pass this count to your first Child component from parent

Now you can access this count in your FirstChild component using this.props.count and you can get 5 value passed from your third component.

Comment: that´s my schema:                                                                              
                             Component1           Component3
                                         |   with callbaclk          |    with props
                                         |         Component3

Comment: you want to pass data from component3 to Parent/Component2 then from Parent/Component2 to component1?

Comment: that´s my schema:                                                                              
                             Component1           Component3
                                         |   with callbaclk          |    with props
                                         |                                  |                               
                                        └   Component3         ┘                           
                               <Component3 course={course},callback={callback}>

Comment: Its backend database schema?

Comment: he seem child receive 'props' from on component(father1) and this seem child component need send a callback function to the other component(father2)

Comment: why you want to send callback to parent component? Callback is passed in React from parent to child so that child can send data back to parent using that callback.

Comment: it´s right the Callback is for <parent> to <child>, it`s true, the situation is, i habe some file called: "ManageCoursePage.jsx" that control the main tasks of my local api json database, that they´re create, update, so now i want create the erase using a callback in the <son> called "CourseList.jsx", but this component receive the props of the other <father> called "CoursesPage.jsx"..i dont know how i can manage it..thks bro in advance 4 your time...

Comment: so you want to pass callback from child to parent and then from parent to other child?

Comment: I want to pass callback from child to parent1 and then from parent2 to pass 'props' to the seem child.